# Large apk file created by eclipse

Tags: android, apk

I have cloned an android application that uses NDK ,then I compiled it using eclipse and it works fine,but size of the apk file is over 150 MB ,I changed its format to zip  and extracted it ,the folder includes toolchain folder with 400 MB size,what is wrong?

Comment: What do you mean `cloned`?

Comment: It was an open source application in code.google.com and I'm wokring on it